# Issuing multiple rollbacks to my python sqlite session ,causes my docker container to crash? How to avoid this crash?

Tags: python, docker, sqlite, flask

I am using this docker container to run my flask web app, FROM `python:3.8.16`. In my flask app, I have a code in a `@after_request` function where I rollback my sqlite session whenever any rest API returns a 500 response code.The frontend sometimes requests more than one rest API parallelly and if they both send a 500 response , the container simple crashes because I am  issuing multiple rollbacks. how to avoid this container crash.

**Session is created using sessionmaker of sqlite3**

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
session = sessionmaker(self.db)
```

**After request containing session rollbacks**

```
@app.after_request
def end_request(response):
    if response.status_code not in [200,201,202]:
        session.rollback()
```

Comment: what is `session` in `session.rollback()`? is it the same `session` in `session = sessionmaker(self.db)`? If so, it does not have a `.rollback` method there, not sure how it works

Comment: session = session()

Comment: what error do you get before it crashes?

Comment: The container receives a SIGKILL command.